# Django app while dockerizing gives "Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/" but doesn't show up on browser

Tags: python, django, docker, gunicorn, wsgi

So I am a beginner in docker and Django. What I have here is a django app which I am trying to dockerize and run. My requirements.txt has only django and gunicorn as the packages.

I am getting the below in terminal after building and running the docker image:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 26, 2021 - 06:57:22
Django version 3.2.6, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN mkdir /Django

WORKDIR /Django

ADD . /Django

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The commands I am using are:

```
docker build . -t myproj    

docker run -p 8000:8000 myproj
```

I have tried adding allowedhosts = ['127.0.0.1'] in settings.py but still I am getting "The site can't be reached. 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Not able to see the "Congratulations" screen.

Please help me out with this.

P.s: I am using windows machine

***Updates***

I tried running the below line and got the following output:

```
docker exec 8e6c4e4a58db curl 127.0.0.1:8000

OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"curl\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

Comment: Try `docker exec myproj curl 127.0.0.1:8000` and add the result in the question body.

Comment: What  URL are you trying to access the server?

Comment: @M.Rostami I have put it in the question at the end

Comment: @ShashankV I tried both http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and 0.0.0.0:8000 but doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried to reach the container using its own IP address (172.17.x.x by default)?

Answer (score 0):

Without your settings.py, this can be hard to figure out. You say you have `allowedhosts = ['127.0.0.1']` in there and that should definitely not be necessary. It might actually be what's blocking your host, since requests from your host come from a different IP address.

I've made the following Dockerfile that creates a starter project and runs it

```
FROM python:latest
RUN python -m pip install Django
RUN django-admin startproject mysite
WORKDIR /mysite
EXPOSE 8000
CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

If I build it and run it with

```
docker build -t mysite .
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 mysite
```

I can connect to http://localhost:8000/ on my machine and get the default page (I'm on Windows too).

I hope that helps you to locate your issue.

PS: Your `curl` command fails because curl isn't installed in your image, so it failing has nothing to do with your issue.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried your started project code and tried running it but now in the terminal (using vscode) it is stuck at "Watching for file changes with StatReloader" and when I am trying to connect to localhost on browser still not able to connect. says site cant be reached localhost refused to connect

Comment: Can you try running it from the command line rather than from vscode? The fewer moving parts you have, the easier it'll be to figure out what's wrong. Also, when you've started the container, check that it's running by doing `docker ps`. Check that status is 'up' and that it has `0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp` under 'ports'

Comment: tried with command prompt still it is stucked at watching for file changes with statreloader. :(

and yes status is up

Comment: I just checked the logs on mine and it's also watching for file changes. So that's normal. It's weird that you can't access it with http though. If you do `docker inspect <container>` somewhere in the JSON you get back there is an IP address. For me it's 172.17.0.2. Can you try going to `http://<ip-address>:8000/` from your browser?

Comment: I tried, still nothing. is there something wrong with win 10 home? I was planning to run the same code on virtual box linux image.